# How do I dynamically add javaFX shapes to a shared pane through its controller class?

Tags: java, javafx

I am creating an application which requires a graph consisting of nodes and edges to be displayed. Each node is represented by a Circle object and each edge is a Line.

I have multiple scenes in the application, but the graph needs to be displayed in more than one of these scenes. So, I have created a fxml file using scene builder which only consists of an anchor pane which I want to be able to display my graph on. I have included this fxml file in the other scenes that require the graph to be displayed, so that I can use one controller to add the graph to a single anchor pane which will be shared across many scenes.

However, when I add my circles and lines as children to the anchor pane using the controller, they are not visible. Using the debug tool I can see that they are indeed children of the anchor pane, but they are not being displayed. I can see objects that I add to the anchor pane using scene builder (for example, I used scene builder to add a circle to the anchor pane and I could see that when running my GUI, but none of the other children which I added via code).

To reduce the scope of the problem, I attempted to create a single circle and add it to the anchor pane through my controller class. Despite being a child of the anchor pane, this circle was not visible when running the GUI.

GraphPaneController.java

```
public class GraphPaneController {
    @FXML Pane paneGraph;
    public void addCircle() {
        
        Circle circle = new Circle();
        circle.setFill(Color.RED);
        circle.setRadius(50);
        circle.setCenterX(0);
        circle.setCenterY(0);
        
        paneGraph.getChildren().add(circle);

    }
}
```

MainMenuController.java

```
public class MainMenuController {
    public void startButtonClicked() {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("graph_pane.fxml"));
        Parent root = loader.load();
        GraphPaneController gpController = loader.getController();
        controller.addCircle();
        Frontend.setRoot("gamemode_select");
    }
}
```

Frontend.java

```
public class Frontend extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage mainStage) throws Exception {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("mainmenu.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 600, 400);
        mainStage.setScene(scene);
        mainStage.show();
    }
    
    public static void setRoot(String fxml) throws IOException {
        newScene.setRoot(loadFXML(fxml));
    }

    public static Parent loadFXML(String fxml) throws IOException {
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(Frontend.class.getResource(fxml + ".fxml"));
        return fxmlLoader.load();
    }

}
```

mainmenu.fxml

```
<VBox prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="640.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/19" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="graphvis.group30.MainMenuController">
  <children>
    <AnchorPane id="ap" maxHeight="-1.0" maxWidth="-1.0" prefHeight="-1.0" prefWidth="-1.0" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
         <children>
            <ImageView fitHeight="400.0" fitWidth="640.0" opacity="0.19" pickOnBounds="true" />
            <Label layoutX="198.0" layoutY="112.0" text="Graph Colouring Game">
               <font>
                  <Font size="24.0" />
               </font>
            </Label>
            <Button id="btnInputGraphFromFile" layoutX="255.0" layoutY="200.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#btnInputGraphFromFileClicked" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="130.0" text="Input graph from file" />
            <Button id="btnCreateRandomGraph" layoutX="255.0" layoutY="235.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#btnCreateRandomGraphClicked" text="Create random graph" />
            <Label layoutX="197.0" layoutY="138.0" prefHeight="61.0" prefWidth="245.0" text="Made by Nathan Macdonald, Kasper van der Horst, Oguz Kagan Yarim, Miriam Espinosa, Dorina Sili" textAlignment="CENTER" wrapText="true">
               <font>
                  <Font size="10.0" />
               </font>
            </Label>
            <Button layoutX="255.0" layoutY="269.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#btnQuitClicked" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="130.0" text="Quit" />
         </children>
    </AnchorPane>
  </children>
</VBox>
```

graph_pane.fxml

```
<AnchorPane fx:id="paneGraph" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/19" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="graphvis.group30.GraphPaneController" />
```

gamemode_select.fxml

```
<VBox prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="640.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/19" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="graphvis.group30.GamemodeSelectController">
  <children>
    <AnchorPane maxHeight="-1.0" maxWidth="-1.0" prefHeight="-1.0" prefWidth="-1.0" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
      <children>
            <fx:include source="graph_pane.fxml" />
            <Label layoutX="139.0" layoutY="14.0" prefHeight="63.0" prefWidth="159.0" text="Select Gamemode:" wrapText="true">
               <font>
                  <Font size="18.0" />
               </font>
            </Label>
            <Button fx:id="btnGamemode1" layoutX="299.0" layoutY="33.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#btnGamemode1Clicked" text="untill death" />
            <Button fx:id="btnGamemode2" layoutX="384.0" layoutY="33.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#btnGamemode2Clicked" text="timed" />
            <Button fx:id="btnGamemode3" layoutX="440.0" layoutY="33.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#btnGamemode3Clicked" text="random " />
            <Button fx:id="btnBack" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="360.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#btnBackClicked" text="back" />
      </children>
    </AnchorPane>
  </children>
</VBox>
```

When viewing the gamemode select screen, I expect to see the circle that I added to the graph pane through the GraphPaneController, but it is not there. What do I do so that I can add visual components to a pane which is shared across multiple scenes?

Comment: If you want to continue with your current approach, see [nested controllers](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/19/javafx.fxml/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#nested_controllers) in the documentation.  With fx:include, a controller (GraphPaneController) is created and its reference can be injected via @FXML into the containing controller (GamemodeSelectController), but just one, not multiple.  You can use the injected reference from a click handler in GamemodeSelectController rather than loading new fxml (which will create a new controller for a view unattached to the scene graph).

Comment: Thanks @trashgod - I like that idea. Could you give me an idea of what this `GraphView` class would look like? What functionality do I need to implement for this viewer to display the graph from `GraphModel`?

Comment: Reviewing your code, probably, if you add the following lines to GamemodeSelectController, you will see a circle display `@FXML private GraphPaneController graphPaneController;` and in the `initialize` function `graphPaneController.addCircle()`, while also removing all code but `Frontend.setRoot("gamemode_select");` from `startButtonClicked`.

Comment: Note that all I am doing is trying to work out untested patches to your code snippets to make it do something (which may not actually be what you ultimately want), on the other hand, trashgod is trying to provide a more fundamental potential solution to your underlying requirements.

Comment: You're loading `graph_pane.fxml` twice. You load it once, explicitly, in `startButtonClicked()`, and you modify the `AnchorPane` that's created when it's loaded that time via the call to the controller. So that `AnchorPane` will contain a circle. However, you never actually display that `AnchorPane` anywhere. Then you load `gamemode_select.fxml`, which loads another copy of `graph_pane.fxml` via the `<fx:include>`. At no point do you call `addCircle()` on the controller that is created the second time you load `graph_pane.fxml`, so no circle is displayed in that instance of the `AnchorPane`.

Comment: @trashgod thanks for your help, I got it to work using a model class and a viewer class

Comment: You can [answer your own question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/17463/163188).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I got this to work by creating a model class (`GraphModel`) and a viewer class (`GraphView`) for the graph. The model class handles creating the vertices and edges, and the viewer class is reponsible for displaying the graph.

`GraphView` extends `javafx.scene.layout.Pane` and contains an `AnchorPane` attribute, containing the elements of the graph to be displayed, which can be added to scenes by calling a `getAnchorPane` method on the `GraphView` object.